# postfix problems with pattern in virtual file

Tags: linux, virtual, postfix-mta

We are trying to forward all emails to a specific email address. I think everything is set up okay, such as 'main.cf' and 'virtual-regexp' files. If we put the following in the 'virtual' file, the forwarding works correctly:

@ourmail.com mainid@ourmail.com

However, if we try to use the following in 'virtual' to send ALL email to the ID, it ignores it and sends it to the original user:

(.*) mainid@ourmail.com

We got the idea for the above from the following question and answer:
[postfix 2.9.6.1 forward all mail to an external mail address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270439/postfix-2-9-6-1-forward-all-mail-to-an-external-mail-address)

Any ideas why the pattern '(.*)' doesn't work? We've tried so many different patterns that our heads are starting to spin.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Mail server configuration is offtopic. Try superuser or serverfault instead.

Answer (score 0):

we solved the issue.

You need to complete the steps listed in the link above.  But, in addition, you need to comment out the following lines in main.cf (if they are there) before restarting the postfix process:

## virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

## virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual